# Does subprocess inherit python's linux capabilities?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, linux-capabilities

I'm using a program to issue a tc command via the subprocess module, but tc is outputting `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`

To solve this, I have given python the `CAP_NET_ADMIN` capability with the `epi` flags, but I still am not able to issue the tc command.

```
$ getcap /usr/bin/python3.5
$ /usr/bin/python3.5 test-capabilities.py 
CompletedProcess(args=['tc', 'qdisc', 'add', 'dev', 'eth0', 'root', 'pfifo'], returncode=2, stdout=b'', stderr=b'RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted\n')
$ sudo setcap cap_net_admin+eip /usr/bin/python3.5 
$ /usr/bin/python3.5 test-capabilities.py 
CompletedProcess(args=['tc', 'qdisc', 'add', 'dev', 'eth0', 'root', 'pfifo'], returncode=2, stdout=b'', stderr=b'RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted\n')
$ sudo /usr/bin/python3.5 test-capabilities.py 
CompletedProcess(args=['tc', 'qdisc', 'add', 'dev', 'eth0', 'root', 'pfifo'], returncode=2, stdout=b'', stderr=b'RTNETLINK answers: File exists\n')
```

if `CAP_NET_ADMIN` allows a process to modify network interfaces, and the `+i` flag given in `setcap` indicates that subprocesses should inherit the capabilties given to the executable, why am I still getting the operation not permitted error. I'd expect to get the File exists error, like I do above when running python via sudo.

Comment: Based on [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/632520/), at least as recently as 2015 capabilities weren't inherited through an `execve()` call.